# Creating a casper instance with additional configuration such as injecting jQuery

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'd like to use jQuery with CasperJS, but it seems that I fail to inject jQuery into remote document.

The code below is simplified code to show where the problem may exist.

I know I need to use `casper.evaluate` later but I'm failing to injecting jQuery.

How am I supposed to change the code in order to inject jQuery right?

**This code works**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.yahoo.co.jp', function() {

    this.echo("hello");

});
```

**This code doesn't work**

```
var casper = require('casper');
casper.create({
    clientScripts: ['jquery-2.2.2.min.js']
});

casper.start('http://www.yahoo.co.jp', function() {

    this.echo("hello");

});
```

**Current directory & where jQuery file locates**

```
$ pwd
/Users/Hayato/Desktop

$ ls | grep "jquery"
jquery-2.2.2.min.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with injecting jQuery. You mixed up how to get the `casper` instance.

Use either

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ['jquery-2.2.2.min.js']
});
```

or

```
var casper = require('casper');
casper = casper.create({
    clientScripts: ['jquery-2.2.2.min.js']
});
```

The issue is that `create()` gives you the instance that you can work with, but you're currently throwing it away.

Comment: ahhh!!! That's right! I created the instance without putting it into any variable... Thanks!!